# Why XAMPP does not work? rewrite html file, and do action apache, but not changing.(codeigniter use)

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

First use, codeIgniter on Xampp and localhost development.
so fine, useful. but time ago, 1day(develeping, programming), so not change, immediatly code on webbrowser, on action in apatche on Xampp.

I searching this site, Stackoverflow, and caching, 80port, httpd... or etc, I try that, but no use.

so, I feel, slow active on webBrowser and my code active different, time watse. but I think about that, experience. 
 I don't know php develop enviroment setting and Xampp apatche server. so I reinstall Xampp.
 May possible, comment anything please. Thank you.

Comment: I find problem, I use IDE Tool, so I setting on index.php, another folder(server file root context.) I changing that. and solution before problem~. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rewrite, to answer.
I do self solutionig. It's my misstake.
I find problem, I use IDE Tool, so I setting on index.php, another folder(server file root context. $view_folder, $application_foler, $system_folder is worng referenced.) so immediatly don't working on. so, I changed, $views_folder, $application_foler, $system_folder is rewrited that, ../htdocs/..system, etc. So posible, solutioning before problem~. Thank you.